# Keeping the size of ImageView constant for different size images

Tags: android

I have a standard image in my app for every song that doesnt have an album cover. Now, for the few that do have in there metas saved an album cover I want to replace the "standart" image.
The problem however is, that the new image changes the size of my layout. It basically now adjusts to the new images' dimensions. I wish that would not be the case. I simply want to replace my old image with a new one ( both are circles ) without altering the size at all.

This didnt work for me:

```
        vh.CoverArt.SetImageBitmap(output);
```

Thanks for your help! :)

Sure:

```
              <ImageView
                  android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/btn_musicalnote"
                    android:id="@+id/musical_note"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp" />
```

Comment: can you update your question with the xml for your imageview?

Comment: just did. it was an imagebutton before that this caused other size related issues...

Comment: You are using ``wrap_content``, so ``ImageView`` will expand to fit the new image, change your layout to your desired size.

Answer (score 0):

When you use **wrap content** then your view will expand according to the size of resource dimensions you use. In your case ( Imageview size will increase or decrease according to the size of image you use in it.)
To set a fix size of your imageview define height and width attributes manually. For example below code will produce an imageview of size 40X40 dp.

```
<ImageView
              android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_musicalnote"
                android:id="@+id/musical_note"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp" />
```

You can change height and width attributes according to your need.

Comment: Right, but I want the imageview to take the size of the actual file from the resources folder...